# Who is the (police uniform) Mexican highway shooter in Sicario?

Tags: sicario

At the end of the shooting on the highway, a hooded person dressed in dark with a Mexican flag tag and a baseball cap with what looks like a police star (but seems to have six points rather than the Mexican [Federal Police seven points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Police_(Mexico)))shoots at Kate and misses.

[image: Person in question]

Is the role and goal of that person known? Was it a police officer who mistook the American soldiers as cartel members (and for some suicidal reason decided to engage)? Was it a member of the other cartel gunmen disguised in a police uniform?

Am I correct about the star's point count? Is it a different police branch or did the film makers just get the costumes wrong (It looks like  Silvio's uniform also has a six-point star tag)?

[image: six point star on Silvio's uniform]

Comment: Maybe the guy from the spotter vehicle but then he should have wear a regular uniform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like he is a State police officer, which is what Silvio is (an American equivalent would be a State trooper) he was most likely a dirty cop and was paid by the cartel to assist in the assult on the motercade

Comment: The star logos seem to be all wrong. Possibly for legal and/or political reasons. The script states that the shooter is a state police officer. This is foreshadowed by Alejandro's warning "Keep an eye out for the state police. They're not always the good guys." and the "spotter vehicle"/"lone wolf" on the left lane after the convoy leaves the prison.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the eight shooters in the red and green cars (over two lanes from the convoy) were designed to be a distraction to US personnel in the five black SUV vehicles... allowing the guy in the police uniform to slip in behind the US personnel and fire into the black vehicles. Why the police-uniformed gunman chose that side of the black vehicles to attack (as well as choosing the last one in the convoy) seems to be a tactical error on his part. It would have made more sense if he attacked the convoy from the passenger side (instead of the driver side) of the vehicles, which would have provided some concealment and protection to him from the US personnel that had moved towards the red and green cars. Also, it would have been very unlikely that Guillermo would have been in the last vehicle-- he would have been placed in one of the inner vehicle of the convoy. The tinted rear and side windows would have forced the gunman to guess.